# brew --prefix libxml2 gives me a non-existent path

Tags: homebrew, libxml2

Just install libxml2 on my system using brew

```
brew update
brew install libxml2
```

Checking the path of the installation

```
brew --prefix libxml2
```

gives me an output of `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2`, however when i try to `cd` into that path
`cd /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.9_2` it tells me the path is non existent

any advise? :(

Comment: What's your Homebrew version? (`brew --version`)

Comment: @nwellnhof  \
Homebrew 2.0.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision c74f2; last commit 2019-02-02)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision e126e; last commit 2019-02-02)

Comment: show  `brew --config`